# Finding all the connected covering spaces of $\Bbb RP^m \times \Bbb RP^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Consider the space $\Bbb RP^m \times \Bbb RP^n$, with $m,n>1$. How many classes of connected covering spaces exist for this space? Construct a representant for each class.

**What I know:** I know the following theorem:

[image]

We have that $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^m \times \Bbb RP^n) \cong \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$.
I have some doubts:

Is $p:S^m \times S^n \to \Bbb RP^m \times \Bbb RP^n$ given by $p(x,y)=\{(x,y),(-x,-y)\}$ the universal cover? or is it $p(x,y)=\{(x,y),(-x,-y),(x,-y),(-x,y)\}$?

Are the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ the trivial subgroup, $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_2=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$? If that's right, there are 3 connected covering spaces. How can we compute $(S^m \times S^n)/\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and  $(S^m \times S^n)/\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: What do you mean by $p(x, y) = \{(x, y), (-x, -y)\}$? $p$ is a function, it has only one value.

Comment: I thought it was like that because $\Bbb RP^n$ is the quotinet space of $S^n$ identifying $x$ with $-x$

Comment: No, the map $S^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ is given by $x \mapsto [x]$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$ under the equivalence relation $x \sim -x$. So $[x] = \{x, - x\}$.

Comment: But what's the universal cover here then?

Comment: If $\widetilde{X}$ is the universal of $X$ and $\widetilde{Y}$ is the universal cover of $Y$, then $\widetilde{X}\times\widetilde{Y}$ is the universal cover of $X\times Y$. The universal cover of $\mathbb{RP}^m$ is $S^m$ and the universal cover of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is $S^n$, so the universal cover of $\mathbb{RP}^m\times\mathbb{RP}^n$ is $S^m\times S^n$.

Comment: Please share your knowledge answering the question of the OP :(

Comment: First note that $(S^m\times S^n)/\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 = (S^m/\mathbb{Z}_2)\times(S^n/\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Next, note that there are three subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ - these determine distinct coverings.